# c# mvc 4 append returned view

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a MVC 4 project where I want to call a controller from view A and than append the returned view B in view A.
something like that:

view A (aspx):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

  function HeadBtn_Click() {

   /////
      var url = 'IVR/';
      window.location.href = url;
  ////this works, but I want to stay in view A

    //// example of what I want:
     divContant.innerHTML = ////The returned view here////

    }
  </script>

  <body>

   <input type="image" onclick="HeadBtn_Click();" src="../../Images/buttonHodaot.png">

   <div id="divContant"> ////Append Here//// </div>

  </body>
```

view B(aspx):

```
   ////I will have alot more to append, but just for now:
  <div>
     <p>To Append</p> 
  </div>
```

thanks

Comment: have you tried to make View B as a partial view?

Comment: You need to do it via Ajax or render Partial view depending on what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach (if you really want to render the view `B` after view `A` loads)..

Make use of AJAX and get the response HTML of view B, then append it to `divContent` div. Like this,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function HeadBtn_Click() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: url,
      dataType: 'HTML',
      success: function(data) {
          $('#divContant').html(data);
      }
   });
  }
</script>
```

Hope it helps, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can use RenderAction and return viewB as partial view

```
<div id="divContant"> 
 @{Html.RenderAction("controllerName","actionName");}
</div>
```

http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/Q8V2130113-RenderPartial-vs-RenderAction-vs-Partial-vs-Action-in-MVC-Razor.html